# How to redefine last row within a loop

Tags: excel, vba

The following code inserts rows when a blank cell in col B is encountered and specific values are present in col A.  The inserted rows are populated with values from arrays depending on the condition. Each time rows are inserted I need the last row value to change, so the code can evaluate the next blank cell in col B but I can’t figure out how to redefine the last row.  How do I make this work?

1. What kind of loop do I need to use?
2. Where do I redefine the last row?
3. How do I move to the next blank cell in column B?

Thank you very much,

```
    Sub MissingValues()

Dim zArr As Variant
Dim yArr As Variant

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim i As Long
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("QC")

Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

yArr = Array(Array("HD300 Removed Alt", "EGFR", "", "", "L861Q", "5"), _
       Array("HD300 Removed Alt", "EGFR", "", "", "KELRE745delinsK", "5"), _
       Array("HD300 Removed Alt", "EGFR", "", "", "L858R", "5"), _
       Array("HD300 Removed Alt", "EGFR", "", "", "T790M", "5"), _
       Array("HD300 Removed Alt", "EGFR", "", "", "G719S", "5"))

zArr = Array(Array("HD200 Removed Alt", "BRAF", "", "", "V600E", "10.5"), _
        Array("HD200 Removed Alt", "KIT", "", "", "D816V", "10"), _
        Array("HD200 Removed Alt", "EGFR", "", "", "KELRE745delinsK", "2"), _
        Array("HD200 Removed Alt", "EGFR", "", "", "L858R", "3"), _
        Array("HD200 Removed Alt", "EGFR", "", "", "T790M", "1"), _
        Array("HD200 Removed Alt", "EGFR", "", "", "G719S", "24.5"), _
        Array("HD200 Removed Alt", "KRAS", "", "", "G13D", "15"), _
        Array("HD200 Removed Alt", "KRAS", "", "", "G12D", "6"), _
        Array("HD200 Removed Alt", "NRAS", "", "", "Q61K", "12.5"), _
        Array("HD200 Removed Alt", "PIK3CA", "", "", "H1047R", "17.5"), _
        Array("HD200 Removed Alt", "PIK3CA", "", "", "E545K", "9"))


LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

i = 3
Do While i <= LastRow

Debug.Print i
Debug.Print LastRow

        If IsEmpty(Cells(i, 2).Value) = True Then
          Cells(i, 2).Value = "header"
            If InStr(1, Cells(i, 1).Value, "HD200", 1) > 0 Then
                Rows(i & ":" & i + 10).Insert Shift:=xlDown 'Insert 11 rows
                Worksheets("QC").Range("A" & i & ":F" & i + 11).Value _
                = Application.Index(zArr, 0)
                 'Recalculate LastRow
                 i = i + 12
                 LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

            ElseIf InStr(1, Cells(i, 1).Value, "HD300", 1) > 0 Then
                Rows(i & ":" & i + 4).Insert Shift:=xlDown 'Insert 5 rows
                Worksheets("QC").Range("A" & i & ":F" & i + 5).Value _
                 = Application.Index(yArr, 0)
                 i = i + 6
                'Recalculate LastRow
                LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            Else
                i = i + 1
            End If
          'LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        End If

        'LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Loop


Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you insert or delete lines in excel worksheet you have to do it from the last line.

```
For i = LastRow To 3 Step -1
    'Your Code Goes Here...
Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

customizing this pseudocode to your specific syntax should work-

```
 if ( i+1 = LastRow)  
    custom code here... 
    increment i
```

Comment: What kind of loop do i need? I've tried for and while loop, neither of them worked for me. Thanks

Comment: Using CodeFromthe510's approach, you can use `for` or `do-while`. The `for`-loop can increment i for you, `do-while` requires manual incrementation.